# Cannot Access Deployed OpenShift App

Tags: java, git, maven, gwt, openshift

I just deployed an app to OpenShift. I migrated to the new Bronze plan, created an app with the JBoss EAP6 cartridge on a medium gear and added MySQL and PHPMyadmin. I compiled my GWT/JavaEE app, copied war from target to deployments folder and renamed it to ROOT.war, I also enabled "skip maven build".

The app gets deployed (git push) but I cannot access it since it just keeps showing 404 error.  I noticed some errors in the logs (I tailed the server) http://fpaste.org/88339/13957444/, but can't make out anything from the errors. How do I even begin to handle this? especially the 404 on the deployed app?

Answer (score 0):

First fire command like "git clone git url for your app"

then you will get a folder for your application and in that delete "src" folder and if your app is not using maven then also delete "pom.xml" after that there is a "webapps" folder and place your war file in that folder.Thats it..

Now from command line go to your app directory and fire below commands one by one ->

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "your message"
3. git push